# Getting data from a google sheet for the previous XX days

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm logging calls, emails and meetings using Google sheets.  I am trying to get a chart of results based on a number of days in the past, 7, 30, last month, current month, etc.  I am able to do exactly what I need to do using a fixed date but I can't figure out how to convert that to a date range.

Here is what is working:

```
={ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(FILTER(CRM!M2:M2510,CRM!N2:N2510>=VALUE("2018-06-01 00:00:00"),CRM!N2:N2510<=VALUE("2018-08-01 23:59:59"),CRM!M2:M2510<>"")),ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIF(FILTER(CRM!M2:M2510,CRM!N2:N2510>=VALUE("2018-06-01 00:00:00"),CRM!N2:N2510<=VALUE("2018-08-01 23:59:59")),SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(UNIQUE(FILTER(CRM!M2:M2510,CRM!N2:N2510>=VALUE("2018-06-01 00:00:00"),CRM!N2:N2510<=VALUE("2018-08-01 23:59:59"),CRM!M2:M2510<>"")),"*","~*"),"?","~?")))})}
```

I need to change the value from a fixed date to a number of days in the past.  What do I need to change in this formula?  I tried using `TODAY() -7` but I keep getting an error saying that I am missing brackets.  When I use `(TODAY()-7)` I just get an `#ERROR`.

How can I change the `VALUE("fixed date")` to `VALUE(TODAY -7)`?

Comment: `VALUE(TODAY()-7)`

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like "2018-06-01 00:00:00".

Then use this conditions for filter to filter the last 7 days:

```
Arrayformula(datevalue(left(CRM!N2:N2510),10))>=datevalue(today()-7)
,
Arrayformula(datevalue(left(CRM!N2:N2510),10))<=datevalue(today())
```